# World of tanks Python list comparison from json

Tags: json, list, python-2.7, parsing

ok I am trying to create a definition which will read a list of IDS from an external Json file, Which it is doing. Its even putting the data into the database on load of the program, my issue is this. I cant seem to match the list IDs to a comparison. Here is my current code:

```
def check(account):
global ID_account
import json, httplib
if not hasattr(BigWorld, 'iddata'):
    UID_DB = account['databaseID']
    UID = ID_account
    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('URL')
        conn.request('GET', '/ids.json')
        conn.sock.settimeout(2)
        resp = conn.getresponse()
        qresp = resp.read()
        BigWorld.iddata = json.loads(qresp)
        LOG_NOTE('[ABRO] Request of URL data successful.')
        conn.close()
    except:
        LOG_NOTE('[ABRO] Http request to URL problem. Loading local data.')
    if UID_DB is not None:
        list = BigWorld.iddata["ids"]
        #print (len(list) - 1)
        for n in range(0, (len(list) - 1)):
            #print UID_DB
            #print list[n]
            if UID_DB == list[n]:
                #print '[ABRO] userid located:'
                #print UID_DB
                UID = UID_DB
    else:
        LOG_NOTE('[ABRO] userid not set.')  
    if 'databaseID' in account and account['databaseID'] != UID:
        print '[ABRO] Account not active in database, game closing...... '
        BigWorld.quit()
```

now my json file looks like this:

```
{
"ids":[
  "1001583757",
  "500687699",
  "000000000"
  ]
}
```

now when I run this with all the commented out prints it seems to execute perfectly fine up till it tries to do the match inside the for loop. Even when the print shows UID_DB and list[n] being the same values, it does not set my variable, it doesn't post any errors, its just simply acting as if there was no match. am I possibly missing a loop break? here is the python log starting with the print of the length of the table print:

```
INFO: 2
INFO: 1001583757
INFO: 1001583757
INFO: 1001583757
INFO: 500687699
INFO: [ABRO] Account not active, game closing......
```

as you can see from the log, its never printing the User located print, so it is not matching them. its just continuing with the loop and using the default ID I defined above the definition. Anyone with an idea would definitely help me out as ive been poking and prodding this thing for 3 days now.

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but seeing the data in your json file, my guess is that you're comparing integers with their string representations. That is, you're comparing `1001583757` with `"1001583757"`.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Try printing the types of the values just before the if match condition - `print type(UID_DB)
            print type(list[n])`

Comment: @Blckknght, yes I am under the assumption that is the case however when I run the code it prints the value from the list as 1001583757, instead of having it contain the quotes. Should I try setting the list response as a variable and then running the comparison?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Your suggestion was exactly what I needed, TY so much. The comparison didn't match because the first variable was interger and the second variable was Unicode, so I simply added in the conversion string and now the code processes perfectly. TY, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this was found by @VikasNehaOjha it was missing simply a conversion to match types before the match comparison I did this by adding in

```
list[n] = int(list[n])
```

that resolved my issue and it finally matched comparisons.